# load more data from new json url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Im trying to load more data from new json url, for eample first id is 33532 and then 84.
The code load only from the first, how can I modifiy it to support other id when clicking?

```
<script>
    id="33532";
    categoryAddr = "http://www.geektime.co.il/wp-json/samsungApi/v1/posts?cat="+id;
    $.getJSON(categoryAddr,function(data){
        json=data;

    jQuery(function ($) {
    $.each(json, function (i, value) {
        var list = "<li class='hidden' >" 
        + "<h1>" + value.title + "</h1>" 
        + "<img src='" + value.image + "' alt=''/>"
        +"<h2>" + value.excerpt + "</h2>";
        $('.hold').append(list);
        });

    function loadMore(){
        $(".hold .hidden").slice(0,5).removeClass("hidden");
    }

    loadMore();

    $("#btnLoadMore").on("click",loadMore);        

    });
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this script a function that relies on ID and call the function.

```
<script>

    function callAPI(id) {
        categoryAddr = "http://www.geektime.co.il/wp-json/samsungApi/v1/posts?cat="+id;
        $.getJSON(categoryAddr,function(data){
            json=data;

        jQuery(function ($) {
        $.each(json, function (i, value) {
            var list = "<li class='hidden' >" 
            + "<h1>" + value.title + "</h1>" 
            + "<img src='" + value.image + "' alt=''/>"
            +"<h2>" + value.excerpt + "</h2>";
            $('.hold').append(list);
            });

        function loadMore(){
            $(".hold .hidden").slice(0,5).removeClass("hidden");
        }

        loadMore();

        $("#btnLoadMore").on("click",loadMore);        

        });
    }); 
}
callAPI('33532');
</script>
```

You can now call the `callAPI` function in your events.

Comment: TNX!
but how can I first load from 33532 and after every click on "load more" change the id (for example ++id)?

Comment: This would need a rework. Something like this perhaps: http://pastebin.com/6kn1JwY9 I'd advise you to learn the basics of Javascript before asking such questions, as this is a simple operation.